# How to add the array value when the key names are same?

Tags: php

I am populating an array in foreach loop

```
foreach ($value as $key ){
   $array[$key[label]]= $key[name];
}
```

when the labels are same it over writes the value to that key.

Question: when the key values are same I wanted to add the values and store to that key. Any idea?

for example:

```
$key[name1]=5
$key[name2]=4
$key[name1]=3
then the $key[name1]=8(5+3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
foreach ($value as $key ) {
   if (isset($array[$key[label]]) {
      $array[$key[label]] += $key[name];
   } else {
      $array[$key[label]] = $key[name];
   }
}
```

Oh...and actually you should or wrap `label` inside quote or it's a variable and you should prepend the $.

Answer (score 2):

Use an isset check inside the loop:

e.g.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   if (isset($otherarray[$key])) {
        $otherarray[$key] += $value;
   } else {
        $otherarray[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($value as $key ){
    if(!array_key_exists($key['label'], $array))
        $array[$key['label']] = 0;

    $array[$key['label']] += $key['name'];
}
```

Assuming the values are integers as in your example.